# Sending email based on Timezone of IP address

Tags: marketing-cloud, send-email, timezone

Is it possible to do User-Initiated send that takes into account the timezone of the IP address *or something other than IP address*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't send based on the recipient because you won't know what timezone the recipient will be in until they open the email.

If the subscriber has their timezone stored as a profile attribute/data extension field then you might be able to create a query to build your audience and have an automation run every hour.